# Composition of groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, symmetry

Let's say we have a system of interacting particles that can divided into two populations. The symmetry group of each population is $G$, and the two populations are identical, so that I can exchange them and the system remains invariant (see figure). I think the symmetry under exchange of the two populations should be described by the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_2$, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group).
[image]

**My question is:** what is the symmetry group of the whole system? Intuitively it should be some kind of composition between $\mathfrak{S}_2$ and $G$, but which one? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us formalize it the following way :

$$Y=X_1\cup X_2 $$

This is a disjoint union. Set $S(*)$ to be the symmetry of $*$. We know that $S(X_1)=S(X_2)=G$. Then $S(Y)$ acts on $Y$, set $S_1$ the set of symmetry fixing $X_1$ then they fix $X_2$, hence $S_1$ is $S(X_1)\times S(X_2)=G^2$. Now we have that $S(Y)/S_1$ is the group of permutation of $\{X_1,X_2\}$ hence it is $\mathfrak{S}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Now I claim that the quotient admits a section hence you have :

$$S(Y)=(G\times G)\rtimes_{\phi} \mathfrak{S}_2$$

Finally we have to determine $\phi$, I claim that $\phi((1,2)).(g_1,g_2)=(g_2,g_1)$ so that it is non trivial and it just permuts both coordinates. So you have your group.

Furthermore the same technique can be used to show that if $Y=X_1\cup...\cup X_n$ then :

$$S(Y)=G^n\rtimes_{\phi}\mathfrak{S}_n $$

Where $\phi(\sigma).(g_1,...,g_n)=(g_{\sigma(1)},...,g_{\sigma(n)})$. We actually say that this is the wreath product of $G$ with $\mathfrak{S}_n$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) :

$$S(Y)=G\wr \mathfrak{S}_n $$

Edit : the fact that $S(Y)/S_1$ admits a section obviously depends on your situation, but it most certainly has. Anyway the wreath product is usually what you need to formalize this situation : $n$ objects with each the same symmetries ($G\times...\times G=G^n$) and the symmetries of their configuration ($S(Y)/G^n$).

Comment: Many thanks! If I understand it correctly, you use the notation $\mathfrak{S}_2$ for the symmetric group, while I used the notation $S_2$. So I have just edited my question in order to unify the notation.

Comment: I'm not an expert of the topic, so I'm not completely sure to understand the problem of the section that you mentioned. In my case $G=\mathfrak{S}_a\times\mathfrak{S}_b$, so does $S(Y)/S_1$ admit a section in this case?

Comment: @user2983638 Yes, for the section, if you know a little group theory, say you have $N\triangleleft G$ and $G/N=Q$, you must have seen that this doesn't imply (at all) that $G=N\times Q$. If you know more group theory (semi-direct product) you would think that $G=N\rtimes_{\phi}Q$ but this is not always the case either. It appears that there is a good caracterisation of semi-direct product namely if $\pi:G\rightarrow Q$ is the canonical projection then $G$ is a semi-direct product iff $\exists$ a group morphism $s: Q\rightarrow G$ such that $\pi\circ s=Id_Q$.

Comment: @user2983638, in that case $s$ is called a section. If you haven't such a section then it is kind of hopeless to understand the group $S(Y)$ (there are techniques though but it is rough). Now for your last question it will have a section if $a\geq 3$ and $b\geq 3$. The reason is that $Z((\mathfrak{S}_a\times\mathfrak{S}_b)^n)$ is trivial. But it is not explainable in one comment I am afraid. If you are brave you can read : http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/GroupExtensions.pdf. It is related to the classification of extensions.

Comment: Thanks Clément, your help has been very precious!